# Node pagination with express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have to build and API as server side, that should provide results in pages of 10 entries, using only Node with express (no other packages).

- A query parameter `p` specifies which page to return, starting with 1. If the `p` parameter is omitted, the default value is 1.
- If the client side asks for `/api/stories?p=1`, they should only get 10 stories, starting from the newest one.
- If `p=2`, the API must return the second batch of 10 stories.
  When a page of stories is returned it must be ordered with the most recent story first.
- If `p` is greater than the last page number, the API must return the last available page.
- The `page` value is the currently returned page. If the requested page `p` is greater than the last page number, the returned `page` value will indicate the last page number.
- The `pageCount` value is the number of the last non-empty page.*

This is what I have for pagination...

```
//pagination
const pageLimit = 10;
app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    "posts": posts.slice(-pageLimit).reverse(),
    "page": 1,
    "pageCount": Math.ceil(posts.length / 10)
  });
});
```

The return is correct as 10 posts per page, 11th, 21st, 31st posts are pushed on 2nd ,3rd page etc...
Now my problem comes when I try to advance from page 1 to page 2 (as a next page) nothing happens...

I'm guessing I have to implement something like a a next but I don't have any idea how to do it

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

after scratching my head 2 days, I found a solution that works for me..Thank you **num8er** for pointing me in right direction...

```
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(posts.length / 10);
  let page = parseInt(req.query.p);
  if (!page) { page = 1;}
  if (page > pageCount) {
    page = pageCount
  }
  res.json({
    "page": page,
    "pageCount": pageCount,
    "posts": posts.slice(page * 10 - 10, page * 10)
  });
});
```

Comment: upvoted! since you are returning json response i had to ask a question, if the person changes the data in the url and hits enter, how do you prevent them from seeing raw json on the screen

Comment: easiest and simple way I came across!

Comment: What is the value of posts? Where are you getting or defining?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out:

```
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  const postCount = posts.length;
  const perPage = 10;
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(postCount / perPage);

  let page = parseInt(req.query.p);
  if(page < 1) page = 1;
  if(page > pageCount) page = pageCount;

  const from = postCount - ((page - 1) * perPage) - 1; // ex.: 44 - ((1 - 1) * 10) -1 = 43 (44 is count, 43 is index)
  let to = postCount - (page * perPage); // ex.: 44 - (1 * 10) = 34
  if(to < 0) to = 0;

  res.json({
    posts: posts.slice(from, to).reverse(),
    page,
    pageCount
  });
});
```

P.S. If `posts` array retrieved from database - I strongly recommend to use database powers to retrieve necessary data. Otherwise retrieving thousands of page and then slicing array to 10 items is will result with performance issues.

Comment: no is just a test file with in-memory. No db involved....your solution is nearly what I need. Just try to figure out how to tweak because is trow some error as "ReferenceError: pages is not defined".

Comment: @Gallex fixed, my fault

Comment: @Gallex fixed according correct size of posts count to not get out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

```
export default (limit, offset, count) => {
  const pageData = {};
  limit = limit > count ? count : limit;
  offset = offset > count ? count : offset;

  pageData.page = Math.floor(offset / limit) + 1;
  pageData.pageCount = Math.ceil(count / limit);
  pageData.pageSize = Number(limit);
  pageData.totalCount = count;

  return pageData;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You are missing a part, here's a practical example:

```
let records = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
];
let pageSize = 5;

function paginate(page = 1) {
    //when page is 1, we go from index 0 to index 4 
    //that's the first 5 records.
    return records.slice(pageSize * (page - 1), pageSize * page);
}

console.log(paginate(1));
console.log(paginate(2));
console.log(paginate(3));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fe4s2qxv/

Answer (score 0):

**Node pagination with sequelize** 
client needs to provide page and pageSize

```js
const page = 1
const pageSize = 2
const offset = page * pageSize
const limit = offset + pageSize
return model.findAll({
             attributes: [],
             include: [{}],
             limit,
             offset
       })
       .then((tasks) => res.status(200).send(tasks))
       .catch((error) => {
             console.log(error);
             res.status(400).send(error);
       });
```